# Python - Importing packages by running a script

Tags: python, package

I have a script which is importing lots of packages, including `import numpy as np`.

I have lots of scripts which need to import all of these packages (including some of my own). To make my life easier, I have a file called `mysetup.py` in my path to import all the packages. It includes the statement in a function called "import numpy as np".

I run "main.py". It runs the following

```
from mysetup import *
import_my_stuff()
np.pi()
```

"mysetup.py"

```
def import_my_stuff(): 
   import numpy as np
return
```

However, I am unable to use numpy in "main.py" - this code will fail. Any suggestions as to why?

Comment: Remove the importings from inside the `import_stuff` function and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is a consequence of a very important features of Python: *namespaces*.

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces
- https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/

Basically, in your case, when you do that (`numpy`) import inside the (`import_my_stuff`) function, you are defining the code object `numpy`/`np` *inside* the function *namespace*. (scope, if you prefer).

To solve your issue (*the way you are doing*; not the only way), you should simply import everything at the module top level (without a function encapsulating the imports):

**`mysetup.py`:**

```py
import numpy as np
# other modules...
```

**`main.py`:**

```
from mysetup import *
np.pi()
```

Answer (score -1):

Imports in functions are not the best idea.
But you can just define whatever imports you need in top level code of `mysetup.py`

```
import numpy as np
```

and then it will be available when you import * from mysetup

```
from mysetup import *
print(np.pi)
```